# How do I update UWP projects' nuget packages via the CLI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, nuget

All .NET framework projects that use Nuget have a packages.config per project. When I run something like:

```
nuget update MySolution.sln -Id PackageName -Version 1.2.3
```

It will update all projects in my solution that use this package to the specified version (1.2.3 in this case)

However, I'm finding that this does NOT work for UWP projects. UWP does not use packages.config and instead put the package references directly into the csproj file. As a result, this is literally what nuget update says when I run it:

```
Found 2 projects with a packages.config file. (A.csproj, B.csproj)
```

where A and B are my .NET Framework projects that still have a packages.config file. But this list doesn't include my new UWP projects.

Is there another command for nuget update that will work with UWP projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I update UWP projects' nuget packages via the CLI?

This is a known issue for the `packagereference`. At the moment, NuGet CLI does not support automatic package updates to the the new .NET Core `.csproj` format, you can refer to the below GitHub issue for details:

[support for updating references into csproj from commandline(s)](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4103)

Besides, as test, the workaround using following command line does not work with UWP project

```
dotnet add package <PackageName> --version <version>
```

Indeed, currently it is very inconvenient to manage packages **outside of** Visual Studio for UWP with `packagereference`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, that is a very old support ticket... thanks for the info.